# Adding pictures to powerpoint slide and having them fill up the slide automatically

Tags: powerpoint

I have some a set of 4 pictures that I would like to ad to a powerpoint slide. I'm wondering if it somewhat possible to drop these pictures into the slide, select them and have the fill up the whole slide by 2x2?

Looking for a faster solution than my current manual work.

Comment: You could try to program a solution in VBA or any of several other languages, then ask here if you run into problems with your code. You can't, however, expect someone to respond to a question like this with the code you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you take a look at SlideMight, a utility for merging data with PowerPoint templates; both text and images, in slides and tables. The usage is in principle similar to mail merge, with some more advanced stuff. Maybe this could help you with your task.

See [www.slidemight.com](http://www.slidemight.com).

Disclaimer: I am the developer and seller of SlideMight.